# (Earth's) magnetic field

Tags: earth, magnetic-fields

Always when we want to represent the magnetic field of the earth we see a similar image:

[image]

My question is, what exactly does this show? What are the blue and orange lines, what do they represent? Why are they curved like that? I have a vague idea about field lines, but I do not fully comprehend this. An explanation would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin of blue & orange lines (in *your* [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_magnetic_field) image) represent North & South poles of Earth. *Indeed*, Earth could be imagined to be a magnetized spherical shell. Those are the magnetic field lines (a concept introduced by Faraday). Field lines are introduced as an aid of visualizing electric & magnetic fields. They're commonly referred to as "[lines of force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_force)". They have several characteristics associated with them - like *beginning at north pole & ending at south pole; don't intersect, etc.*

You could draw infinite number of magnetic field lines within a given region of space. In magnetism, these curved lines *simply* imply that a compass placed in any of these lines would deflect tangentially to the curves indicating magnetic poles of Earth. These lines could be drawn using a bar magnet *itself*..!

Sadly, I must also add that your question is possibly related to [Magnetic field lines](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/38561) already asked here...

Comment: why these randomly scattered magnetic field lines in earth core choose the north/south poles as points of exit and entrance?

Comment: @Hammar - Because the geomagnetic north pole is actually offset by several degrees from the geographic south pole.  The red lines (assuming the top of the image points toward ecliptic north) are north/positive magnetic field lines while the blue are south/negative field lines (sign with respect to outward normal of surface).